# Karma $filter Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n

Tags: angularjs, webpack, karma-webpack

I'm in the process of updating our external AngularJS module. Once I updated our Webpack and Karma-Webpack, I started getting this unknown provider error.

I wish I could use `ng-strict-di`, but when I add this into our application, everything works fine. So the issue only exists in the unit tests.

I've broken this down, so it's simpler. In the example I've provided, the issue occurs when I'm trying to inject `$filter` into my unit test.

### Dependencies section of package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.7.5",
    "angular-resource": "1.7.5",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "moment": "2.15.2",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.23",
    "ngstorage": "^0.3.11",
    "platform": "1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "1.6.3",
    "@types/angular-resource": "^1.5.8",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.54",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.51",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.34",
    "@types/ngstorage": "^0.3.35",
    "@types/platform": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-mocks": "1.7.5",
    "del": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-exit": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.3.2",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.12.0",
    "gulp-jshint-xml-file-reporter": "^0.3.3",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.8.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^0.6.6",
    "gulp-sort": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.6",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "gulp-useref": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-wrap": "^0.10.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.10.2",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-webpack": "^4.0.2",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.14",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1",
    "yargs": "^7.0.2"
  }
}
```

### Webpack.config

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require("webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin");

let libraryName = "shared-angular-services";

let plugins = []

outputFile = libraryName + ".min.js";

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  context: __dirname + "/app",
  entry: "./index.ts",
  devtool: "source-map",
  //devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      /*{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: "tslint-loader",
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        }, */ {
        // all files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  output: {
    library: libraryName,
    path: __dirname + "/target",
    filename: outputFile,
    // export itself to umd
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]
  },
  node: {
    fs: "empty"
  },
  externals: {
    angular: "angular",
    "angular-resource": "angular-resource",
    ngstorage: "ngstorage",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    lodash: "lodash",
    moment: "moment",
    "moment-timezone": "moment-timezone",
    platform: "platform"
  },
  stats: {
    warningsFilter: /System.import/
  }
};
```

### Karma-Webpack Config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpackConfig = require('../../webpack.config');
webpackConfig.resolve = webpackConfig.resolve || {};
webpackConfig.resolve.modules = webpackConfig.resolve.modules || [];
webpackConfig.resolve.modules.push('node_modules');
webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.[tj]+sx?$/,
    loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
    exclude: [
        /node_modules/
    ],
    enforce: 'post',
    options: {
        esModules: true
    }
});

var entry = path.resolve(webpackConfig.context, webpackConfig.entry);
var preprocessors = {};
preprocessors[entry] = ['webpack', 'coverage', 'sourcemap'];
preprocessors["test/karma/**/*.ts"] = ['webpack'];
preprocessors["test/karma/**/*.js"] = ['webpack'];

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({

        // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
        basePath: '../../',

        // frameworks to use
        // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        webpack: webpackConfig,
        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: "errors-only",
            noInfo: true,
            logLevel: "error"
        },

        // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
        // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
        preprocessors: preprocessors,

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            "node_modules/angular/angular.js",
            "node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.js",
            "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
            "node_modules/moment-timezone/moment-timezone.js",
            "node_modules/lodash/lodash.js",
            "node_modules/platform/platform.js",
            "node_modules/ngstorage/ngStorage.js",
            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",

            "node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js",
            entry,

            "test/karma/filter/join-by.pipe.spec.ts",
            "test/karma/model/sometest.spec.ts"

            //test
        ],
        mime: {'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']},


        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
            "test/karma/**/*conf.js",
            'target/**/*.min.js'
        ],

        reporters: ['dots', 'junit', 'coverage-istanbul'],

        // the default configuration
        junitReporter: {
            outputDir: 'target/testResults',
            outputFile: 'test-results.xml'
        },

        coverageIstanbulReporter: {

            // reports can be any that are listed here: https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbul-reports/tree/590e6b0089f67b723a1fdf57bc7ccc080ff189d7/lib
            reports: ['html', 'cobertura', 'text-summary'],

            // base output directory. If you include %browser% in the path it will be replaced with the karma browser name
            dir: "target/testResults/coverage/",

            // if using webpack and pre-loaders, work around webpack breaking the source path
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,

            // stop istanbul outputting messages like `File [${filename}] ignored, nothing could be mapped`
            skipFilesWithNoCoverage: true,

            // Most reporters accept additional config options. You can pass these through the `report-config` option
            'report-config': {

                // all options available at: https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbul-reports/blob/590e6b0089f67b723a1fdf57bc7ccc080ff189d7/lib/html/index.js#L135-L137
                html: {
                    // outputs the report in ./coverage/html
                    subdir: 'html'
                }

            },

            // enforce percentage thresholds
            // anything under these percentages will cause karma to fail with an exit code of 1 if not running in watch mode
            thresholds: {
                statements: 1,
                lines: 1,
                branches: 1,
                functions: 1
            }

        },


        // web server port
        port: 9876,


        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,


        // level of logging
        // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
        logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,


        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: false,


        // start these browsers
        // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
        //browsers: ['Chrome'],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

### Unit test

```
import * as angular from "angular";
import { JoinByFilter } from "../../../app/filter/join-by.pipe";

describe("Join By Filter Test", function() {
    let joinByFilter;
    let value;
    let $filter;

    beforeEach(function() {
        (angular as any).mock.module("angular-filter");
        (angular as any).mock.inject((_$filter_) => {
            $filter = _$filter_;
        });
        joinByFilter = new JoinByFilter();
    });

    it( "Should register itself with Angular", function() {
          expect($filter("JoinByFilter")).toBeTruthy();
    });
})
```

### The final Error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n
        https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$injector/unpr?p0=nProvider%20%3C-%20n
            at node_modules/angular/angular.js:138:12
            at node_modules/angular/angular.js:4905:19
            at Object.getService [as get] (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5065:32)
            at node_modules/angular/angular.js:4910:45
            at getService (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5065:32)
            at injectionArgs (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5090:58)
            at Object.invoke (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5114:18)
            at UserContext.WorkFn (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3459:20)
            at Object.window.inject.angular.mock.inject (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3429:42)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/karma/filter/join-by.pipe.spec.js:1:7888)
            at <Jasmine>
            at Object.window.inject.angular.mock.inject (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3422:25)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/karma/filter/join-by.pipe.spec.js:1:7888)
            at <Jasmine>
        TypeError: t is not a function
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/karma/filter/join-by.pipe.spec.js:1:8050)
            at <Jasmine>
```

I notice that it tends to break on the angular.mock.inject

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.